# Moving mysql database to new partition with different partition "type"

Tags: mysql, partitioning, linux

Sorry, Possibly a dumb question, but something which needs clarification.

Currently mysql is stored on sda which is around 1TB. Now our DB has outgrown that, almost !!. So trying to create new partition of 3 TB so that we can move DB to new partition.

Current sda is partition type 83 (aka Linux)

We added new sdb partition of 3 TB but creating partition type with "linux" can only go max up to 2 TB.

My question is, does it matter if we move SQL files to "new" partition with different partition "type" ? e.g. 85 (linux Extended, which can go up to max size of 16TB)

[image]

Comment: I would expect MySQL to be oblivious of the FS type.

Comment: Thanks for response @RickJames
Sorry, to clarify your comment, Answer is NO ? I can NOT move mysql to different "type"  ?

Comment: Assuming that the OS can copy any file between filesystems, then it "does not matter if you move mysql".  There may be configuration changes to make.  Are you moving the executable, the entire directory tree, one table, one database, ...?

Comment: entire directory "/var/lib/mysql"

Comment: Sounds good.  Just be sure that the config file (my.cnf or whatever) knows where the tree is now.

Comment: Don't use fdisk if you need partitions with >2TB size. Use parted and a GPT partition table. See: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/fdisk-unable-to-create-partition-greater-2tb.html

Answer (score 0):

You could omit partitioning /dev/sdb and just put a filesystem on it.

```
mkfs.xfs -L MYSQLDATA  /dev/sdb
```

(other filesystems like ext3/4 will also work).

And in /etc/fstab

```
LABEL=MYSQLDATA /var/lib/mysql  xfs    defaults 1 2
```

To migrate:

```
systemctl stop mysql.server
mount /dev/sdb /mnt
chown mysql: /mnt
mv /var/lib/mysql/* /mnt/
umount /mnt
```

Then use:

```
mount /var/lib/mysql
restorecon -Rv /var/lib/mysql # if you have selinux
systemctl start mysql.service
```